# TypeError: array_map(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback or null, function "test" not found or invalid function name

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP, I am trying to create a function called "test" to convert array object into string, and apply "test" function on an array consist of array. My code is listed here:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class testCronjob extends Command{

public function handle(){
        $failDetail= [['id'=>1], ['id'=>2]];
       
        function test($v){
            return (implode(' ', $v));
        }
        
        $result = array_map("test", $failDetail);
        
    }
```

}
I got an error listed here:

```
TypeError: array_map(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback or null, function "test" not found or invalid function name
```

Can you please help to figure it out? Many THX!

Comment: Don't define one function inside another. Place the test function outside of the handle function. Also, both functions are inside a class, so using just `test` as the function name may or may not work. You may need the test function completely outside of the class.

Comment: @aynber if `test` gets made into a proper class method, then `[$this, 'test']` as the callable argument for array_map should also work.

Comment: The code you've shared does not trigger this problem, as `handle()` is not called anywhere. Is there more code that you haven't shared?

Comment: I do not see any reason why the above should not work? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Cyclonecode Stab into the dark: namespaces…!?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I can never remember if it does or doesn't work that way

Comment: @deceze Ah, of course that must be the problem =) Well would be easier to see a more complete example of the code.

Comment: I updated the code sample, please have a look.

Comment: Please also share your attempts to resolve the problem. Did you check the recommendation from CBroe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into this and also reading the comment from @deceze I figure this must be because you are using a namespace:

```
<?php
// This works since we are not using a namespace
class Foo
{
   public function handle()
   {
      $failDetail= [['id'=>1], ['id'=>2]];
      function test($v) {
        return implode(' ', $v);
      }
      $result = array_map("test", $failDetail);
   }
}
```

Here is a couple of different ways to solve this:

```
// add the callback as a method in the class
<?php
namespace YOURNAMESPACE;

class Foo
{
   public function handle()
   {
     $failDetail= [['id'=>1], ['id'=>2]];
     $result = array_map([$this, 'test'], $failDetail);
   }

   public function test($v)
   {
     return implode(' ', $v);
   }
}

// Use a lambda for the callback
<?php
namespace YOURNAMESPACE;

class Foo
{
   public function handle()
   {
      $failDetail= [['id'=>1], ['id'=>2]];
      $result = array_map(function ($v) {
        return implode(' ', $v);
      }, $failDetail);
   }
}
```